# Get the String sql from a Couchbase N1qlQuery DSL?

Tags: couchbase, querydsl, couchbase-java-api

After building a query object like in this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758577/1643558) or examples in [couchbase java n1ql queries docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html) can we get the string query before sending it to the server? I do not want to send it to the server. Merely want to build it with the DSL, then get the string of the complete query with parameters in place, what would have gone to the server,  and process it in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Statement` can be converted to a String just by calling `toString()`:

```
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.Statement;

import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.Select.select;
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression.i;
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression.path;
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression.s;
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression.x;

Statement statement = select(path(i("travel-sample"), "*"))
    .from(i("travel-sample"))
    .where(x("name").eq(x("$airline_param"))
        .and(x("type").eq(s("airline"))));

System.out.println(statement);
```

OUTPUT:

```
SELECT `travel-sample`.* FROM `travel-sample` WHERE name = $airline_param AND type = "airline"
```

As you can see, this does not do any parameter replacement. Arguments are sent to the server separately from the statement. If you want to see what gets sent to the server, you can call `N1qlQuery.n1ql()`:

```
JsonObject args = JsonObject.create().put("$airline_param", "FooFliers");
N1qlQuery q = N1qlQuery.parameterized(statement, args);

JsonObject statementAndArgs = q.n1ql(); 
System.out.println(statementAndArgs);
```

OUTPUT (prettified):

```
{
  "statement": "SELECT `travel-sample`.* FROM `travel-sample` WHERE name = $airline_param AND type = \"airline\"",
  "$airline_param": "FooFliers"
}
```

If you need the arguments to be inlined then you'll need to do that part yourself, being extra careful to escape string arguments properly.

Comment: thank you kindly. Can you give me the imports for this? If its saved somewhere ... I'm working on Statement statement  part but was not able to get i guess its from Functions?

Comment: a question (or suggestion if its notthere yet) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319538/couchbase-n1qlquery-dsl-an-empty-but-smart-expression-to-initialize-with-when